# Авторизация бота Telegram по LDAP

Tags: php, telegram-bot, ldap

Пытаюсь создать бота для телеграмма. Сообщения скриптом в телеграмм отправляются и документы, а вот с выполнением команд бота - застрял.
Дело в том, что скрипт, который должен их обрабатывать, находится на сервере, доступ к которому по ldap авторизации.
Т.е. телеграмм не может его выполнить.
Подскажите, что делать в этом случае?

Comment: Нужно написать какой-нибудь фронтенд / сценарий, который будет доступен по HTTPS. Логично же!

Comment: rкаким образом если при любом обращении к https://domen.ru просит логин и пароль